# Android SDK MediaPlayer ﹕ error (1, -1004)

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I use Android sdk.
I change data source of the media player in loop.
Sometimes ( I couldnt find any cause ) application doesn't play new source.
It is not about the source, the sources are correct. Also, the application may play the source next time.

Some parts of my code:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            player.start();
        }
    });
```

--

```
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
            //Do the work after completion of audio
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            playSound("en", new word);
```

---

```
public void playSound(String oLanguage, String word){



    String link = LINK; //WORKING, I am sure


    try {
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(link);

        player.prepare();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Error while playing word: ", word);
        Log.i("Error while playing link: ",link);
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a question buried in this post, I just know it.

Comment: I get error(1, -1004) i dont know why, i dont know how to fix.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that Error code?